# Django Tutorial 1 errors

Tags: python, django

I started the django tutorial part 1 a couple weeks ago and came back and noticed that Poll was changed to Question.  when I first tried changing the models.py file from

```
class Poll(models.Model):
```

to

```
class Question(models.Model):
```

after running:

```
 python manage.py sql polls
```

i get the following error:

```
NameError: name 'Poll' is not defined
```

My first question is if I want to change the name of the class in my models file, how do I do this to avoid such an error?

So, I kept it named Poll to elimate this error.  However, when I got to the part in the tutorial where it says:

> Once you’re in the shell, explore the database API:
>
> > > > from polls.models import Poll, Choice
> > > >
> > > > Poll.objects.all()

but I get the following error:

```
 File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 93, in __repr__
    data = list(self[:REPR_OUTPUT_SIZE + 1])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 108, in __len__
    self._result_cache.extend(self._iter)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 317, in iterator
    for row in compiler.results_iter():
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 775, in results_iter
    for rows in self.execute_sql(MULTI):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 840, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/util.py", line 41, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 128, in execute
    six.reraise(utils.DatabaseError, utils.DatabaseError(*tuple(e.args)), sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 120, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 201, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorclass, errorvalue
DatabaseError: (1054, "Unknown column 'polls_poll.question_text' in 'field list'")
```

So, just wondering what's going wrong here.

Thanks

Comment: i realized that my problem was a noobie mistake.  I didn't change my models.py file correctly.  I only changed the the class name of Poll to Question and didn't change the Choice class' question member     question = models.ForeignKey(Poll) to     question = models.ForeignKey(Question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to migrate your database. But since it is the tutorial, just erase your DB and start over.
Otherwise, take a look into [SOUTH](http://south.aeracode.org).

Answer (score 2):

You changed the name of your Model but you are still accessing it using the old name. You need to access it using the new name now. You will also have to do

> python manage.py syncdb

to sync your database tables once you make changes to models.

```
from polls.models import Question, Choice

Question.objects.all()
```

If you still get database error, delete the database file and run syncdb again. For real development use [South](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you have changed the model class name to `Question` then you should change the lines in tutorial to try as

```
#------------------------v
from polls.models import Question, Choice

Question.objects.all()
```

Also, you will have to do `syncdb` as well.